# Does bounded derivative imply bounded Frechet derivative for real analytic functions?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, analytic-functions, frechet-derivative

Let $f$ be a real analytic function where the convergence radius of the Taylor expansion on any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is $\infty$. Moreover, $\|f'\|_{\infty}\leq O(1)$. Let $A, B$ be two Hermitian matrices. Is it true that

$\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(A+\delta B)-f(A)}{\delta}\preceq O(1) |B|$, where $|B|=\sqrt{B^2}$?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think. I would use the Cauchy integral formula for complex analytic functions
$$h(z) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{|s| =r} \frac{h(s)}{s-z} ds$$
And since $f(A+zB)$ is complex analytic in $z$
$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{f(A+zB)-f(A)}{z} =\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{|s| = r} \frac{f(A+sB)}{s^2} ds$$
Thus, it is enough to assume $f(A+sB)-f(A)$ is bounded for $|s| \le r/\|B\|$ when $A$ is hermitian, which is the case if $f'(z)$ is bounded for $|\Im(z)| \le r$.

Comment: Why does it imply that it cannot be upper bounded by $O(1)|B|$?

Comment: @user07001129 I didn't say it can't, I said your bound is implied (and more or less equivalent) to $|f(A+zB)-f(A)| \le C \|B\|$ for $|Im(z)| < r$ therefore to $|f'(z)| \le C$ for $|Im(z)| < r$. Try things like $f(z) = \int \sin(z^2)dz$ such that $f,f'$ is bounded on the real line but $f''$ is large and $f'$ is not bounded on $|Im(z)| < r$